# Verbose log in Magit

Tags: magit

As far as I remember, verbose log in Magit 1.x was on `lL`. However, in Magit 2 `lL` does something different altogether. I know it is possible to activate verbosity by toggling `--stat` or `--patch` options. However, that's not quite what I need.

Is it possible to generate verbose log, but without any diff details?

Comment: That's all there is at present.

Comment: What do you want to display?

Comment: Author, date and *full* comment, all on separate lines.  Basically, exactly like entry headers with `--stat` option (i.e. without changed file details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just added a new argument to the log popup which allows showing additional information about each commit without also showing the diff or diffstat.

The argument is named `++header` and it behaves *mostly* like git-log's `--format` argument. When that switch is enabled, then the format specified by the new option `magit-log-revision-headers-format` gets combined with a constant format used internally. The result is then used as `--format`s value. That's why I am using another argument, which git does not actually understand and indicate that by naming it `++header` instead of `--header`.